# php static override variable in class

Tags: php

Static variable in php class are override see the below example.

```
class a
{
   public static $v1;

   public function __construct($v)
   {
      self::$v1 = $v;
   }
}

$ob1 = new a(1);
$ob2 = new a(2);
echo $ob1::$v1 . '-' . $ob2::$v1;
output: 2-2
```

why this will not print 1-2 how can we achive this output(1-2) without using none static variable.

Comment: Using `$this->v` and defining variable as not static.

Comment: is it not possible by using a static variable?

Comment: static variables are associated with classes and not instances of those classes. so if you need to have per instance then use instance variables (remove the static keyword)

Comment: As you see from your example - it is not possible.